# Can I take the results from two rows and combine them into one?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 rows of data in a mysql database. Both rows are identical with the exception of one column. What I am looking for is a query that will produce a single row with both distinct values. Can someone please help me out?

An example of the data is:

```
1    Administrator    Test    2009-08-17 03:57:35
1    Miller           Test    2009-08-17 03:57:35
```

What I need is this:

```
1    Administrator    Miller    Test    2009-08-17 03:57:35
```

DISTINCT won't give it to me. I need the additional column *added* or appended to the result set.

---

This is the code I am trying to use.

```
SELECT
t2.msg_id,
t3.lname AS sender,
t4.lname AS recipient
FROM
mail_message AS t1
Inner Join mailbox AS t2 ON t1.msg_seq = t2.msg_seq
Inner Join employee AS t3 ON t3.employee_id = t2.employee_id
INNER JOIN employee AS t4 ON t3.employee_id = t4.employee_id
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  There may be a better approach than forcing your result set to be a single row.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  You can `JOIN` the table onto a copy of itself, with a technique something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM the_table AS t1
INNER JOIN the_table AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id AND t1.test = t2.test AND t1.date_column = t2.date_column AND t1.name < t2.name)
```

Here we arbitrarily name one copy of the table `t1` and the other `t2` and join rows that are identical except for the name.

Note that I do not simply do a `!=` test on the `name`, since that would result in two matching rows: one where `Administrator` is in `t1` and the other where `Administrator` is in `t2`.  To distinguish one identical table from the other, I assert that `t1` will always be the one with a "smaller" (i.e., earlier alphabetically) name.

If there can be three or more identical rows, this will still work, but will return several matches. For example, if `A`, `B`, and `C` are all names in otherwise identical rows, you'd get:

```
A B
B C
A C
```

Comment: Hi Votey, thanks for the excellent example and explanation. I am going to try and rewrite this query as such. I will report back with what I find. Thank you again.

Comment: Well, it looks like you spilt. I'm going to give you the credit for this answer because I am certain that this will do what I need. I will cintinue to work on it. Thanks Votey.

Comment: Votey, I am going to post the actual DDL above. I am basically still getting 2 rows instead of one.

Comment: It was a nice idea but I don't think this is what I need. I need a single row as I stated in my post not multiple rows.

Comment: Your `JOIN` clause includes none of the conditions mine does.  You cannot simply join on the ID, or you will end up with two completely duplicated rows. From the SQL statement you have it's still not clear to me what columns need to be involved, but you do need to include conditions for ALL the fields you want to match, including the inequality as I described above.  The query I wrote will return exactly one row for the conditions you stated.