# Combining two result sets from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I know that there are several many posts on this topic on this website, and the closest one I could find that was similar was:

[Can I take the results from two rows and combine them into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290701/can-i-take-the-results-from-two-rows-and-combine-them-into-one)

I am working on a project that involves 'accounts receivables' and 'accounts payable', but that both of those need data in a single list:

```
date | description | reference | debit | credit
```

I have read about the mySQL UNION statement being used to combine two result sets into one, however, it also appears that the two results sets must match in column count and type according to the below website:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

The problem I'm facing is that the two result sets don't have the same column count as the information for one doesn't directly correlate to the other (which will exclude the use of the UNION statement).  What would be the best practice at acquiring the data from the two tables and sort them based on date?  I'll include my SQL calls below as reference:

Accounts Receivable:

```
SELECT tblARP.*,tblAR.invoiceID,tblAR.ledgerID
FROM Accounting_ReceivablesPayments tblARP
INNER JOIN Accounting_Receivables tblAR ON tblARP.invoiceID = tblAR.invoiceID
ORDER BY deposited
```

Accounts Payable:

```
SELECT tblAPP.*,tblAP.id,tblAP.ledgerID,tblAP.tblName,tblAP.rowID,tblAP.invoice
FROM Accounting_PayablesPayments tblAPP
INNER JOIN Accounting_Payables tblAP ON tblAPP.payablesID = tblAP.id
ORDER BY deposited
```

UPDATE

Per the requests in the comments, here are the columns for the tables:

Accounting_Receivables

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
invoiceID BIGINT NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
ledgerID BIGINT NOT NULL,
note TEXT
```

Accounting_ReceivablesPayments

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
invoiceID BIGINT NOT NULL,
received DATE NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
deposited DATE,
tag VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
```

Accounting_Payables

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
paid TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
invoice BIGINT NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
terms VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'net',
due DATE,
tblName VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
rowID BIGINT NOT NULL,
ledgerID BIGINT NOT NULL,
note TEXT
```

Accounting_PayablesPayments

```
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
payablesID BIGINT NOT NULL,
created DATE NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
deposited DATE,
tag VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
```

Comment: show ur tables data too

Comment: If you want to sort the two data sets together, then a union is the best way. Are there common fields that you could show? I assume a reference, an id, an amount are common to both. Could you create a union of the data that does match? How are you displaying this?

Comment: make the columns match that correlate ... if they don't correlate then make different columns for them using an alias `tbl.column AS new_column`, and use a union.

Comment: do you have any relevant data between the two tables? like an invoice number or something?

Comment: @Hammerstein there are several fields that are common between the two tables, but I need more from one table than the other table in order to fill out the list (date|desc|ref|etc).  How would I get the additional information if I just used the common fields between the two tables?

Comment: @cmorrissey the problem I am running into (as you can see from the two SQL commands) is that one requires less info from one table than the other.  How would I make aliases for things that are missing from one table?

Comment: @JohnRuddell no because one is taking information from another table (e.g. Invoices for Accounts Receivable) whereas the other one is user submitted (e.g. I owe AT&T, car payment, etc).

Comment: ok then just populate an empty string in the place of the table that doesn't have the same number of columns to match the number of records then union.

Comment: @JohnRuddell don't the columns and types have to match with a UNION?  Can't set them all to blank strings. :)

Comment: @user1646428 if you aren't going to show the number of columns for each query and the data that corresponds to the queries I can't hand you the answer with a silver platter.. yea to may need to make a few changes to the suggestion i made... but its a suggestion of what to try.

Comment: @JohnRuddell per your request, I have updated the post.

Comment: just look at this and copy it... you just need to put in NULL when its not going to have a column for that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407864/mysql-select-union-for-different-columns

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks John, I will take a look at it asap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to what I was saying in the comments you should do this

```
(   SELECT 
        tblARP.*,
        tblAR.invoiceID,
        tblAR.ledgerID,
        NULL, -- # -- null values for your rows to match columns
        NULL,
        NULL
    FROM `Accounting_ReceivablesPayments` tblARP
    INNER JOIN `Accounting_Receivables` tblAR ON tblARP.invoiceID = tblAR.invoiceID
    ORDER BY deposited
)

UNION ALL -- # -- union all to include everything

(   SELECT 
        tblAPP.*,
        tblAP.id,
        tblAP.ledgerID,
        tblAP.tblName,
        tblAP.rowID,
        tblAP.invoice
    FROM `Accounting_PayablesPayments` tblAPP
    INNER JOIN `Accounting_Payables` tblAP ON tblAPP.payablesID = tblAP.id
    ORDER BY deposited
)
```

Comment: Thanks John, will check this first thing in the morning!

Comment: John it looks like I was able to use your UNION statement to collect all the records, however, I'm trying to test for a column name so that I can identify which records came from each table "if (isset($results['invoiceID'])) {...}" but that doesn't seem to work.  Thoughts on how I can tell which record came from which table?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117727/php-mysql-query-using-unions-and-locating-which-table-the-data-came-from